# Getting error whens installing Laravolt Avatar package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Please help.

I am getting the following errors when installing this package: https://github.com/laravolt/avatar#integration-with-other-php-project.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ya> composer require laravolt/avatar
Using version ^2.2 for laravolt/avatar
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested package florianv/laravel-swap (locked at 1.3.0, required as ^2.0) is satisfiable by florianv/laravel-swap[1.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package laravel/socialite (locked at v3.3.0, required as ^4.0) is satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - Conclusion: remove florianv/laravel-swap 2.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install florianv/laravel-swap 2.0.0
    - Installation request for florianv/laravel-swap ^2.0 -> satisfiable by florianv/laravel-swap[2.0.0, 2.0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install cache/adapter-common 0.3.3
    - florianv/laravel-swap 2.0.x-dev requires cache/illuminate-adapter ^0.2.0 -> satisfiable by cache/illuminate-adapter[0.2.0].
    - cache/illuminate-adapter 0.2.0 requires cache/adapter-common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by cache/adapter-common[1.1.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - cache/illuminate-adapter 0.2.0 requires cache/adapter-common ^1.0 -> satisfiable by cache/adapter-common[1.1.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: cache/adapter-common[0.3.3, 1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: cache/adapter-common[1.0.0, 0.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: cache/adapter-common[1.1.0, 0.3.3].
    - Can only install one of: cache/adapter-common[1.1.x-dev, 0.3.3].
    - Installation request for cache/adapter-common (locked at 0.3.3) -> satisfiable by cache/adapter-common[0.3.3].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have followed the installation procedure.

This is my composer.json

{
    "name": "bedigit/laraclassified",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Classified Ads Web Application.",
    "keywords": [
        "ads",
        "classified",
        "cms",
        "laravel",
        "php"
    ],
    "license": "Envato",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "~3.0",
        "bedigit/lara-recaptcha": "^1.0",
        "bedigit/laravel-omnipay": "dev-master",
        "bedigit/omnipay-2checkout": "dev-master",
        "bedigit/omnipay-payu": "dev-master",
        "chriskonnertz/open-graph": "~1",
        "cocur/slugify": "^2.3",
        "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^4.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "florianv/laravel-swap": "^2.0",
        "graham-campbell/flysystem": "^5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "jackiedo/dotenv-editor": "1.*",
        "jaybizzle/crawler-detect": "1.*",
        "jaybizzle/laravel-crawler-detect": "1.*",
        "jenssegers/date": "^3.2",
        "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "^1.2",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel-notification-channels/twilio": "^2.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.1",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^1.0",
        "livecontrol/eloquent-datatable": "^0.1.5",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.3.*",
        "mews/purifier": "~2.0",
        "mhetreramesh/flysystem-backblaze": "^1.5",
        "omnipay/paypal": "~3.0@dev",
        "omnipay/stripe": "~3.0@dev",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
        "php-http/message": "^1.6",
        "predis/predis": "~1.0",
        "prologue/alerts": "^0.4.0",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "4.*",
        "pulkitjalan/geoip": "2.*",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^5.0",
        "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "^2.2",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^2.0",
        "spatie/flysystem-dropbox": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.37.0",
        "torann/laravel-meta-tags": "^3.0",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-password": "1.0.*",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "1.0.*",
        "watson/sitemap": "2.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/Functions/admin.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/core.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/plugin.php",
            "app/Helpers/Functions/wordpress.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Larapen\LaravelLocalization": "packages/mcamara/laravel-localization/src/"
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "app/",
            "LarapenIlluminate\": "packages/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/",
            "Larapen\TextToImage\": "packages/larapen/texttoimage/src/",
            "Larapen\LaravelMetaTags\": "packages/torann/laravel-meta-tags/src/",
            "Larapen\Admin\": "packages/larapen/admin/src/",
            "Larapen\Feed\": "packages/spatie/laravel-feed/src/",
            "Larapen\Impersonate\": "packages/lab404/laravel-impersonate/src/",
            "Laravolt\Avatar\": "packages/avatar-master/src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {},
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "lab404/laravel-impersonate",
                "mcamara/laravel-localization",
                "spatie/laravel-feed"
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

Comment: Can you add your `composer.json` file to the post please

Comment: Your Laravel version ?

Comment: My laravel version is 5.8